# Get selected tree node item full path in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, treeview, javafx-2, cloudrail

I have a **TreeView** component and content of it like this:

- root

  - item1
  - item2
  - Folder1

    - Folder2

      - item101
  - item3

I want it to return the path /root/Folder1/Folder2/item101 when selected so that i can put that in the download command.

Below is the sample i have worked out till now(poorly made for testing purpose), problem is that it does not work inside folders, only in the root. I am using **CloudRail** API for Java.

```
List<CloudMetaData> data = cs.getChildren("/");
String path="";
String selectedName = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getValue() ;
            System.out.println(selectedName); 
for (CloudMetaData cmd : data) {
                cache.put(cmd.getPath(), cmd);
                TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<>(cmd.getName());
                             if(selectedName.equals(cmd.getName())){
                                 path=cmd.getPath();
                             }
}
System.out.println(path);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
StringBuilder pathBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (TreeItem<String> item = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    item != null ; item = item.getParent()) {

    pathBuilder.insert(0, item.getValue());
    pathBuilder.insert(0, "/");
}
String path = pathBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this

```
private String GetTreeElementPath(TreeItem<String> item) {

    StringBuilder pathBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (TreeItem<String> parent = item.getParent();
         item != null ; item = item.getParent()) {

        pathBuilder.insert(0, item.getValue());
        pathBuilder.insert(0, "/");
    }
    String path = pathBuilder.toString();

    return path;

}
```